# IS there a replacement for 'taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary' in Drupal 7?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

The closest I have come is `taxonomy_term_load_multiple` but the conditions argument will be deprecated in V8.  They now recommend `EntityFieldQuery` as a replacement.  I am new to coding and have not worked with setting up the conditions for the query and am having trouble finding documentation/tutorials.  If a simpler function exists, I would prefer to use it.  Answers addressing a function or how to use `EntityFieldQuery` are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think an `EntityFieldQuery` would work in this case as you'd be trying to reference two types of entity in the same query (which cannot be done currently). The easiest way would be to build up the query yourself:

```
function taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vid) {
  $terms = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());

  if (!isset($terms[$vid])) {
    $terms[$vid] = array();
  }

  if (!isset($terms[$vid][$nid])) {
    $query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'td')
      ->fields('td', array('tid'))
      ->condition('td.vid', $vid)
      ->condition('i.nid', $node->nid)
      ->orderBy('td.weight');

    $query->join('taxonomy_index', 'i', 'i.tid = td.tid');

    $terms[$vid][$nid] = taxonomy_term_load_multiple($query->execute()->fetchCol());
  }

  return $terms[$vid][$nid];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to coding SQL/PHP/Drupal.  I would have been stuck on EntityFieldQuery for some time before catching the flaw. Every example helps a lot!

Comment: No problem, in case you haven't seen it take a look at [How to use EntityFieldQuery](http://drupal.org/node/1343708), it does a pretty good job of explaining things :)

Comment: If I want to read all terms of a vocabulary (instead of just those on a node, would I be correct to simply delete references to $NID, and delete lines -> condition ('i.nid...); and $query->join....  ?

Comment: You could do definitely, but in that case it would probably be better to use the built-in function [`taxonomy_get_tree()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7). Using that function will give you the correct hierarchy of terms in the vocab, not just a flat list of all terms.

Comment: I saw that on, but couldn't determine of the array returned was flat or a tree and I was not certain how I would read it if it was multilevel.