# Is it possible to use a function which uses $node without the expense of node_load

Tags: 6, performance

In cases where $node is not available but I know the nid, is it possible to mimic $node rather than using node load. I would like to try and cut the expense of performing a full node load..

For example to find a nodes taxonomy by vocab:

```
  $nid = 1;
  $vid = 1;
  $node = stdClass();
  $node->nid = $nid;
  $terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vid);
```

I have tried the above but it doesnt seem to work. I want to use the taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary function but dont want the expense of having to use node_load to get the $node object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I would just look at the source for [taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary/6):

```
function taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vid, $key = 'tid') {
  $result = db_query(db_rewrite_sql('SELECT t.tid, t.* FROM {term_data} t INNER JOIN {term_node} r ON r.tid = t.tid WHERE t.vid = %d AND r.vid = %d ORDER BY weight', 't', 'tid'), $vid, $node->vid);
  $terms = array();
  while ($term = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $terms[$term->$key] = $term;
  }
  return $terms;
}
```

The only thing needed is `$node->vid`.  Note that `vid` in this particular referes to node revision and not vocabulary ID.  If you knew the `vid`, then you could just create your own function:

```
function mytaxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($nodevid, $vid, $key = 'tid') {
  $result = db_query(db_rewrite_sql('SELECT t.tid, t.* FROM {term_data} t INNER JOIN {term_node} r ON r.tid = t.tid WHERE t.vid = %d AND r.vid = %d ORDER BY weight', 't', 'tid'), $vid, nodevid);
  $terms = array();
  while ($term = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $terms[$term->$key] = $term;
  }
  return $terms;
}
```

The problem is that in most cases you don't know the `$node->vid` without doing a [node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6).  Just querying using the nid may or may not be right if you use revisions or start using revisions in the futures.  The proper way to do it would be to `JOIN` the node table into the query so you can use `$node->nid` as an argument instead of `$node->vid`.

Comment: @WestieUK - This is a better answer than mine, so check this one out first :)

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I didn't realise Drupal depended on vid so much for nodes. Makes perfect sense now though.

Comment: No problem.  As a general rule of thumb, if you are using the API then you use $node or $node->nid.  If you are using a direct query then there is a very good chance you need to use $node->vid.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write a query yourself if you don't want to load a whole node object.

It should look something like this:

```
SELECT td.name 
FROM {term_data} td
INNER JOIN {term_node} tn ON tn.tid = td.tid
WHERE td.vid = 1
AND tn.nid = 1
```

Then you can just loop through your results and do whatever you need with them.

I don't have easy access to a Drupal database at the moment, so the query might be slightly out..but it should be enough to get you started :)

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question a couple days ago.  Check the answers [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15744/) and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15755/).